# how to make wcf results appear in raw xml in the browser?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, browser, rss, wcf-client

I am invoking .NET WCF data service. Everything seems to be working fine, but the results show as RSS feeds in both IE9 and Firefox 7. IE only shows the date, and both browsers helpfully offer me to subscribe to this feed. If I view source, it looks properly `<feed ...`

So, apparently, browsers have XSLT template that makes it appear as RSS feed. Is there a way to disable this transformation and view the results as raw XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody sent me a link to [solution](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/how-to-use-xslt-to-style-an-rss-feed/) by email.
Essentially, in Firefox it's impossible (if somebody knows the way - that would be great, but the [suggestion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=338621#c1) is to fill first 512 bytes with comments). And in IE do the following:

1. Click on the Tools menu,
2. Click on the Internet Options sub-menu,
3. Click on the Content tab,
4. Click on the Settings button of the Feed section to bring up Feed Settings dialog box,
5. Un-check the Turn On Feed Reading View option.

Answer (score 1):

View source.

You can also send the requests Fiddler, which has an XML inspector.

Comment: are you just sarcastic or you are saying that's the only way in new browsers? The old way where XML was shown in a tree-like view was much easier to read and faster to see whether there is a problem or not...